# How to use Provide/Inject in Vue.js with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm using Vue.js with TypeScript and [the vue-property-decorator](https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator) package. In theory I can do something like this, according to the documentation:

```
import { Component, Inject, Provide, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator'

const s = Symbol('baz')

@Component
export class MyComponent extends Vue {
  @Provide() foo = 'foo'
  @Provide('bar') baz = 'bar'

  @Inject() foo: string
  @Inject('bar') bar: string
  @Inject(s) baz: string
}
```

However, what if I want to use `@Provide` and `@Inject` on a class that is not a component? For example, if I have `ComponentA` that depends on `ServiceA` that depends on `ServiceB`. How can i set this up?

Answer (score 17):

You provide anything you want from a higher component by using the `@Provide` decorator, and then ask for it in a lower component by using `@Inject`. For example:

In the parent component, you provide the value using `@Provide(<someKey>)`

```
//Parent.vue
<template>
  <div>The parents value: {{this.providedValue}}</div>
  <child />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
  import { Component, Vue, Provide} from 'vue-property-decorator';
  import Child from './Child.vue';

  @Component({components: Child})
  export default class Parent extends Vue {
    @Provide('key') private providedValue: string = 'The value';
  }
</script>
```

Now we've declared a value with the name `key` that can be consumed by all children, multiple levels deep:

```
//Child.vue
<template>
  <div>The childs value: {{this.injectedValue}}</div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
  import { Component, Vue, Inject } from 'vue-property-decorator';

  @Component
  export default class Child extends Vue {
    @Inject('key') private injectedValue!: string;
  }
</script>
```

The property `injectedValue` will now be injected by Vue by walking up on the hierarchy until it finds a provided value with the key `key`.

---

If you want something dependency injection-like, it's best to provide the value at the top, where you create your Vue instance:

```
//index.ts
import Vue from 'vue';
//... imports and configs
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  // Provide values by returning a key-value pair
  provide: () => ({
    'key1': 'value1',
    'key2': 'value2'
  }),
  render: h => h(App)
});
```

Now you can use `@Inject('key1')` in any component of this Vue instance.

Comment: Just now noticed that I didn't fully read your question. For nested services, you'll need some sort of dependency injection container. You can then provide your container at top-level and use it to resolve your services.

Answer (score 1):

You may use vue 3 and class style component, then you have to define provider/inject by this way:

in vue 3 except Component annotation there is Options annotation and we use it to define provide/inject parameters. [More info](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component/issues/406)

```
// Parent component
import { Vue, Options } from "vue-class-component";
import { computed } from "@vue/reactivity";

@Options({
  provide: {
    staticParameter: 'static value',
    reactiveParameter: computed(() => 'Normal computed value'),
  },
})
export default class ParentComponent extends Vue {}
```

```
// Child component
import { Vue, Options } from "vue-class-component";

@Options({
  inject: ["staticParameter", "reactiveParameter"],
})
export default class Timer extends Vue {
  staticParameter!: string;
  reactiveParameter!:string
}
```

Comment: how would we set the value of a reactivate parameter from inside the ParentComponent class?  I can't seem to get this to work at all, only static values