# inject value got undefined in vue 3 with decorator

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I am trying to do Dependency Injection in Vue 3 with tsyringe, but when I Inject in my component, I got an "undefined" value , here the codes:

```
// TYPES.ts
export const TYPES = {
    WARRIOR: Symbol.for("Warrior"),
    WEAPON: Symbol.for("Weapon"),
    CONTAINER: Symbol.for("GlobalContainer"),
}


// globalcontainer.ts
import "reflect-metadata";
import {container as globalContainer, DependencyContainer} from "tsyringe";
import {TYPES} from "@/models/Types";
import {Warrior} from "@/interfaces/Warrior";
import {Weapon} from "@/interfaces/Weapon";
import {Ninja} from "@/models/Warrior";
import {Katana} from "@/models/Weapon";

globalContainer.register<Warrior>(TYPES.WARRIOR, Ninja);
globalContainer.register<Weapon>(TYPES.WARRIOR, Katana);
globalContainer.register<DependencyContainer>(TYPES.CONTAINER, {useValue: globalContainer})

export default globalContainer;

// app.Vue
provide: {
   [TYPES.CONTAINER]: globalContainer
  }
```

i copy paste the plugin decorator from "vue-component-decorator"
when i console.log the component options in Vue,

i have

```
inject: {
  _container: Symbol("GlobalContainer"),
}
```

but when i call that in lifecyle `created`, i got undefined,
here is how i call that

```
// Home.vue
import { Options, Vue } from "vue-class-component";
import { DependencyContainer } from "tsyringe";
import { Inject } from "@/configs/InjectDecarator";

export default class Home extends Vue {

  @Inject(TYPES.CONTAINER)
  private _container!: DependencyContainer;
  
  created() {
    console.log(this._container!); // undefined
  }
}
```

is that any options to call the provide on this component ?? my provider is

```
[TYPES.CONTAINER]: globalContainer
```

i am using ts here

Comment: see if this could help... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46928713/how-to-use-provide-inject-in-vue-js-with-typescript

Comment: yeah i have seen that, vue-property-decator on that question using v7 of vue-class-component, i am using vue-class-component v8, so what i asked for v8 :), well maybe i will go to v7 to be more stabe